# Oracle Apex get_url not setting item

Tags: oracle-apex

I am using apex_page.get_url as link on my query to open a modal dialog.
In the dialog i want to set an item value.

But in util_url i am also using **p_clear_cache** for that page.
In absence of p_Clear_cache , i am having caching issues.
Value for that item gets copied to other items in the IG.

I tried setting item using  DA but it isn't working.

```
p_items-> P1_EMP
p_values-> EMP
```

EMP isn't getting set in the dialog when link is clicked.

Comment: Please provide enough information to reproduce this issue. We cannot see your environment or page. In an earlier question I suggested creating a reproducible case on apex.oracle.com - that would probably help you a great deal.